# Echo radio button value without using submit button in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to echo the selected radio button value without using submit button. I want to display the value of radio button when it is selected. Here is the code.

```
   <?php 
if(!empty($_GET['a1'])){
      $selected = $_GET['a1'];
}
else{
      //if no option was selected, set home as default
      $selected = 'home';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
         <input type="radio" name="a1" value="home"  /> Home <?php echo ($selected == 'home' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
         <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site1" /> Site 1 <?php echo ($selected == 'site1' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
         <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site2" /> Site 2 <?php echo ($selected == 'site2' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
</form>
```

I want the output in the following format
[image]

Comment: How/where do you want to echo the selected value? It would be helpful if you could show an example of your desired output.

Comment: I have added the output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>//jQuery Plugin
<?php 
if(!empty($_GET['a1'])){ $selected = $_GET['a1'];}
else{ $selected = 'home';}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="home" /> Home 
    </label></br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site1" /> Site 1 
    </label></br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site2" /> Site 2 
    </label></br>
</form>
<span class="r-text"><?php echo $selected;?></span>
<script>
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(e) {//jQuery works on clicking radio box
        var value = $(this).val(); //Get the clicked checkbox value
        $('.r-text').html(value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay... I'm updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `onchange` event of the radio buttons with javascript/jquery.

PHP runs server-side, not client-side, so without sending client-side changes to the server, it can't output stuff based on them: you'd need to send a `$_POST` or a `$_GET` request, either by submitting the form or using AJAX. Not necessary for this.

```
<div id="radioMsg"></div>
<form action="" method="post">
         <input type="radio" name="a1" value="home" onchange="showRadio()"  /> Home <?php echo ($selected == 'home' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
         <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site1" onchange="showRadio()" /> Site 1 <?php echo ($selected == 'xyz' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
         <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site2" onchange="showRadio()" /> Site 2 <?php echo ($selected == 'zbc' ? 'This was selected!' : '');?> </br>
</form>
```

Meanwhile in `showRadio():`

```
function showRadio(){
    var radioVal = $("input[name='a1']:checked").val();
    if(radioVal) {
        $( "#radioMsg" ).html("<p>"+radioVal+"</p>");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where you want the changed button's value outputted, so I'm putting it into that div just as an example.

To define the `onchange` event in an external stylesheet instead of inline:

```
$( "input[name='a1']" ).change(function(){
    ... (showRadio's contents go here)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to do a clientside manipulation with PHP(!!!) but this is a jquery solution for **displaying the value of radio button when it is selected**:

```js
$('#myform input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
  var result = $(this).val();
  $('#result').html(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="a1" value="home" /> home</br>
  <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site1" /> site1</br>
  <input type="radio" name="a1" value="site2" /> site2</br>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I want it same way. But when i use it in my code it is not working

Comment: @user6582683 why did you change the question?!! I've been answered your question, maybe your code is not working because of another reason.