# radio buttons without a submit button

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746557/977828) an example of how to use radio buttons without a submit button. I failed to convert this example to Flask.

`static/vehicle.js`:

```
$('#myform input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
    var result = $(this).val();
    $('#result').html(result);
  })
```

`tamplates/example.html`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='vehicle.js')}}"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
    {{ form.example }}
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

`test.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from wtforms import Form, RadioField

SECRET_KEY = 'development'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)


class SimpleForm(Form):
    example = RadioField(
        'Label', choices=[('home', 'home'), ('side1', 'side1'), ('side1', 'side1')])


@app.route('/', methods=['post', 'get'])
def hello_world():
    form = SimpleForm()
    if form.validate():
        print(form.example.data)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render_template('example.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Unfortunately, pressing the radio buttons seems not to print the value.

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to JS you are trying to bind handler to change event when document is not ready and automatic form submission is missing.

It works when you put your code in `$( document ).ready()` callback and add `$('#myform').submit();`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#myform input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
        var result = $(this).val();
        $('#result').html(result);
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
});
```

However some changes to `test.py` need to be done in order to make it a working example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from wtforms import Form, RadioField

SECRET_KEY = 'development'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)


class SimpleForm(Form):
    example = RadioField(
        'Label', choices=[('home', 'home'), ('side1', 'side1'), ('side1', 'side1')])


@app.route('/', methods=['post', 'get'])
def hello_world():
    form = SimpleForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate():
            print(form.example.data)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return render_template('example.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You didn't pass request data to your form which always resulted in error and form validation should be performed only when it's POST request.

Comment: P.S. As soon as I select a radio button the value appears shortly on the bottom. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It is because it is placed there on change event by line '$('#result').html(result)'. Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you it works. How is it possible to remove the bullet points in front of earch radio button?